# Problem with detecting tags on armor in 1.19

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I put the command
`effect give @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:netherite_boots,tag:{Tag:["Custom:26"]}}]}] minecraft:fire_resistance 1 1 true`
in a always active repeat command block, as well as giving myself `/give @s minecraft:netherite_boots{Custom:26}`, however when I wear the boots it does not give me the effect.

Answer (score 0):

You have the selector NBT syntax wrong. You also need to include `minecraft:` in the name of the item. It should be `@a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:"minecraft:netherite_boots",tag:{Custom:26}}]}]` (without the extra `Tag:` tag)

Comment: Interesting, I changed it however it didn't work still

Comment: The new one looks somewhat like ```effect give @a[nbt={Inventory:[{Slot:100b,id:netherite_boots,tag:{Custom:26}}]}] minecraft:fire_resistance 1 1 true```

Comment: @MinecraftKity I've edited the answer, does it work now?

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much I was trying to make some sort of blazeborn armor and it works now!